# грамотная проверка условия js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравсвуйте. Подскажите как сделать грамотную проверку на наличие условия.

Есть кусочек кода который отвечает за удаление нескольких класов по тач событию.  При результате проверки `($('#popup_new_custom_kit').hasClass('popup-show')) = true`
Нужно чтоб код не срабатывал, классы не удалялись

Изначальный код

```
function closeSelectKitTouch() {
    $(document).on('touchstart' && 'touchend', function (e) {
        var container = $(".swipe-menu");
        if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $('.wrapper ').removeClass('active-swipe-menu');
            $('#main-wrap').removeClass('active-swipe-menu');
        }
    });
}
```

Измененый код( так все работает как нужно)

```
function closeSelectKitTouch() {
    $(document).on('touchstart' && 'touchend', function (e) {
        if ($('#popup_new_custom_kit').hasClass('popup-show')) {
            // что  тут должно быть?
        }
        else {
            var container = $(".swipe-menu");
            if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $('.wrapper ').removeClass('active-swipe-menu');
                $('#main-wrap').removeClass('active-swipe-menu');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Меня смущает то что у меня в действиях для if просто пусто.

Собственно в этом и вопрос можно ли так оставлять? Или что там должно быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте "!" перед условием, т.е. :

```
function closeSelectKitTouch() {
    $(document).on('touchstart' && 'touchend', function (e) {
        if (!$('#popup_new_custom_kit').hasClass('popup-show')) { // т.е. "если не"
            var container = $(".swipe-menu");
            if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $('.wrapper ').removeClass('active-swipe-menu');
                $('#main-wrap').removeClass('active-swipe-menu');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Так же обратите внимание на конструкцию:

```
'touchstart' && 'touchend'
```

Не равна ли она true? Честно, не уверен, но есть подозрение, что это будет отрабатывать не так, как ожидается.

Несколько ивентов объявляются просто через пробел:

```
'touchstart touchend'
```

Comment: Спасибо все работает